# Sanitizing bottles/jars for homemade sauce

Tags: storage-method, sauce, cleaning, canning

The recipe for tomato sauce (includes vinegar, sugar and salt) I am using says I can put the bottles in cool water and bring to boil; once they are boiling, they are ready to fill and seal. My question is, do the bottles have to be completely immersed to be sanitized? Thanks, Janet

Comment: For proper sanitization the jars should be brought to a boil and kept at a boil for 15 minutes.

Comment: I suggest reviewing http://nchfp.uga.edu/publications/usda/GUIDE%201%20Home%20Can.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  Any part of the bottle that is not submersed may not reach the proper temperature for sterilization.